# Why does O_CREAT create files only accessible by administrators?

Tags: c++, linux

I have the following simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string data { "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" };

    int file_descriptor = open("some_file.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);
    write(file_descriptor, data.c_str(), data.size());

    cout << file_descriptor << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which for the most part works fine - the data is outputted into the file. But per http://linux.die.net/man/2/open , the `O_CREAT` flag should set the file owner to the effective user ID of the process. I'm compiling/running my application from the terminal, but not with any sort of privileges, so why is the created file only visible to administrators?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Random mischance.  When you use `O_CREAT`, [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) is a 3-argument function, which takes the file mode as the third argument.

You should be using:

```
int fd = open("some_file.txt", O_CREATE | O_WRONLY, 0444);
```

This will create a file with no write permission for anybody (but which your process will be able to write to).

See [`<sys/stat.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html#tag_13_62) for more information about the POSIX symbolic constants to use in place of `0444`.

Comment: Good call.  My first thought was the [`umask(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/umask) being set to some strange value, but this is clearly the correct explanation.

Comment: @sircodesalot: 0444 is indeed S_IRUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH. The R is for read (W for write, X for execute).  The I is simply what was used; I know not why it was there, but it was part of `<sys/stat.h>` before the S_I[RWX]{USR,GRP,OTH} mnemonics were invented.  I learned the octal codes æons ago — and they're more succinct than the S_I* notations.

Comment: You can see the [7th Edition UNIX™ Programmer's Reference Manual (Volume 1)](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/v7vol1.pdf) and look up `stat(2)` to see names such as `S_IFDIR` and `S_IREAD` etc, but no `S_IRUSR` et al.

Comment: Oh, that's useful. I'll need to hold on to that. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm just learning `chmod`, out of curiosity, do the `O_CREAT` permissions you've listed here follow the same rules as `chmod`? IE: `444` => `-r--r--r--` ?

Comment: Yes, they do.  `open()`, `creat()`, `chmod()`, `stat()`, `lstat()` all use the same scheme for permissions bits.  There are a few I've missed out — such as the permissions on shared memory segments and the like — but even those use the same basic scheme.

Comment: Note that in most cases the correct value to use is `0666`, allowing the user's `umask` setting to determine who actually gets write access.

Comment: Using 0666 is the classic security 'semi-conscious' choice.  These days, I think 0644 is often a better, more security conscious choice. You can make the judgement call.